# Monotouch NSInvalidArgumentException Camera

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, camera

I have a problem with my iPad application created with MonoTouch. My application crash by calling the method "TakePicture" Lines "parent.PresentModalViewController (picker, true);", after calling the method "SelectPicture". If I call the method "TakePicture" repeatedly, I have no problems.

The error returned was: "NSInvalidArgumentException Reason:
Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target .".

```
public static class Camera
{
    static UIImagePickerController picker;
    static Action<NSDictionary> _callback;
    static UIPopoverController popover;

    static void Init ()
    {
        if (picker != null)
            return;

        picker = new UIImagePickerController ();

        picker.Delegate = new CameraDelegate ();
    }

    public static void TakePicture (UIViewController parent, Action<NSDictionary> callback)
    {
        Init ();
        picker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
        _callback = callback;                           
        Console.WriteLine("Controller TEST");
        parent.PresentModalViewController (picker, true);
    }

    public static void SelectPicture (UIViewController parent, Action<NSDictionary> callback)
    {
        if(Utils.isIpad()){

            picker = new UIImagePickerController();

            popover = new UIPopoverController(picker);
            picker.Delegate = new CameraDelegate();
            _callback = callback;
            picker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
            picker.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = new SizeF(parent.View.Frame.Width,parent.View.Frame.Height);

            if(popover != null)
                popover.PresentFromRect(new Rectangle(0,0,1000,1),
                                        parent.View,UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any,true);


        }else{

            Init ();
            picker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
            _callback = callback;           
            parent.PresentModalViewController (picker, true);
        }
    }


    class CameraDelegate : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        public override void FinishedPickingMedia (UIImagePickerController picker, NSDictionary info)
        {
            var cb = _callback;
            _callback = null;
            picker.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (true);
            cb (info);
            if(popover != null && popover.PopoverVisible){
                popover.Dismiss(true);                                  
                popover.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("DISPOSE");
            }
            picker.Dispose();   
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm solved my problem.
I'm remove this line :

```
 picker.Dispose();
```